# SQL datetime incorrect format when declaring variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime

I am trying to figure out why this example does not work as expected. I am using SQL Server 2017.

```
DECLARE @testDate DATETIME = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)


SELECT @testDate
```

The first select gives the correct format but instead the second select gives incorrect format. The same happens when i try to cast it from NVARCHAR. Can someone explain to me why this is happening? It's like the variable is not properly storing the result of convert.

EDIT: You can see the results below the first select returns a different format than the second one.

[image: The results]

EDIT2: Thank you for your answer but my question was quite specific on why those 2 selects return different results and it was mainly educational. Not to analyze all the business requirements, I gave 3 lines and i asked why I am getting those results. Simple as that. What i did not understood/notice was that the datetime object was casting the result of the CONVERT to a different format by itself.

Comment: Why are you converting `GETDATE` to a `varchar`? What's wrong with with just `GETDATE()`? If you want the current date without a time, use `CONVERT(date,GETDATE())` (and you probably want to declare `@testDate` as a `date` too).

Comment: The second select gives the *correct* format for a `datetime` (with your system settings).  The first simply returns a string.  There is something that you don't understand, but I'm not sure what.

Comment: If I'm honest, if I run that statement the OP has (today), I'll get a conversion error. maybe that's the problem?

Comment: Date and time datatypes don't have format; they are binary values. `DECLARE @D1 date = CONVERT(varchar(8),GETDATE(),112);` and `DECLARE @D2 date = CONVERT(varchar(30),GETDATE(),126);` will have **exactly** the same binary value, and will be displayed in the date format your presentation layer is using. If you need the value in a specific format that's for your presentation layer to worry about.

Comment: Please the edit this the result sql server returns when you run this. I don't want it without the time i want it in the format of dd-mm-yyyy. Mainly i just need an explanation why the above code returns different results.

Comment: Also they are used in a procedure and they need to represent like that in the logs. Business requirements

Comment: Then your business requirements are wrong or the people making them are (very) misinformed. The data **must** be stored as a data and time datatype, and your *presentation layer* needs to change the way it's **displayed**. **never** store a date/time value as a `varchar` in SQl Server; you'll be entering a world of pain and suffering.

Comment: We dont store it as datetime we need to pass to a different procedure

Comment: After all this it's not clear what your requirement or issue is. But if you don't store dates in the database as a date data type, you're doing it wrong.

Comment: So you're saying that you're intentionally using data where the "date" `'01-01-2019'` is **before** `'19-04-1942'`?

Comment: *"What i did not understood/notice was that the datetime object was casting the result of the CONVERT to a different format by it's self."* It isn't. Your `varchar` value from the `CONVERT` is being implicitly converted back to a `datetime` and then that value is being set to the variable. As `'27-08-2019'` can't be converted to a `datetime`, the conversion error occurs.

Comment: @Larnu yes correctly sorry for the different dictionary i was using if you use varchar then you can keep the format without it being converted. And there is no 'error' I was simply getting results i was not expecting.

Comment: The point you're missing is that none of the date and time data types have a format. if you want a format, that's something you do you your presentation layer; it has nothing to do with your SQL (data).#

Comment: @Larnu 2019-08-05 is different than 05-08-2019 and it's a different format. SQL server stores them in a specific format. And I don't understand where the presentation layer is even relevant in this question since it was a 3 lines question asking why i got those results.

Comment: *"2019-08-05 is different than 05-08-2019 and it's a different format. SQL server stores them in a specific format."* No, no it doesn't.

Comment: Take this [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=abe5d211c23273c43f38cf52a7f57127). Notice that both have the same **presentation** format (DB<>fiddle uses `dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss` for me), and both have the **same** binary value (`0xFB3F0B`). If the format were stored, the binary and return values would be different. They aren't, because they're not. `date`, `datetime`, `time`, `datetimeoffset`, `datetime2` all are stored as a binary value; there is *no* "format" related to them.

Answer (score 2):

You are converting `Varchar` to `DateTime`

See these examples:

```
DECLARE @testDate2 DATETIME = '08-27-2019'
SELECT @testDate2

DECLARE @testDate3 DATETIME = '2019-08-27'
SELECT @testDate3
```

SQL always convert values to default DateTime format.
Both of them converted to `2019-08-27 00:00:00.000`

In this case `SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)`, your selecting formated `Nvarchar`. style 110 => mm-dd-yyyy

If you want to store converted `DateTime` you can use like this:

```
DECLARE @testDate4 VARCHAR(10) = CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), GETDATE(), 110)
```

Comment: Why use an `nvarchar` to store a date, @AntoniosKatopodis? How many dates do you know contain unicode characters? Why are you using an `(n)varchar` at all? Today  (`2019-08-27`) is **not before** `1991-12-31`, but according to your data it **is** (`'27-08-2019' < '31-12-1991' = TRUE`).